# How can I ‘convince’ GHC that I've excluded a certain case?

Tags: haskell, type-inference, gadt, existential-type

I have the following toy implementation of a non-empty list (`NEList`) datatype:

```
-- A type to describe whether or not a list is empty.
data Emptiness :: Type where
  Empty    :: Emptiness
  NotEmpty :: Emptiness

-- The list itself. Note the existential type in `Cons'.
data List :: Emptiness -> Type -> Type where
  Nil :: List 'Empty a
  Cons :: a -> List e a -> List 'NotEmpty a

type EList a = List 'Empty a
type NEList a = List 'NotEmpty a
```

For example it's very easy to define a 'safe head' function that only operates on non-empty lists:

```
eHead :: NEList a -> a
eHead (Cons a _) = a
```

The last is similarly easy, but has a little complication:

```
eLast :: NEList a -> a
eLast (Cons a Nil) = a
eLast (Cons _ b@(Cons _ _)) = eLast b
```

The reason the pattern needs to be like this is to convince GHC that the type of `b` is indeed `List 'NotEmpty`, instead of an unknown existential type. The following code fails for that reason: (`Couldn't match type ‘e’ with ‘'NotEmpty’ ...`)

```
eLast :: NEList a -> a
eLast (Cons a Nil) = a
eLast (Cons _ b) = eLast b
```

I'm fully aware *why* this is happening. What I'd like to know is, can I avoid having to write `b@(Cons _ _)` every time? Is there some *other* way I can restrict the type, so that GHC knows that `b` is referring strictly to something of type `List 'NotEmpty`?

One obvious way is to use `unsafeCoerce` but this defeats the point of the exercise.

---

*For the sake of reproducibility, here is my preamble:*

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall -Werror #-} -- To prevent missed cases.
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures   #-}
import Data.Kind
```

Comment: Are you trying to define an analogue to `tail :: [a] -> [a]` or `last :: [a] -> a`?

Comment: @Koterpillar You're absolutely right, I meant to write `last` not `tail`. Let me fix that. Though I think defining an analogue to `tail` might be very interesting too!

Comment: Tail will be easy. Unfortunately I don't have an answer for your `eLast`...

Comment: @Koterpillar `tail` may be harder than you expect. It's minorly tricky (though at least by now a well-known trick) to even write the type for `tail`.

Comment: @DanielWagner My immediate thought was that it was impossible, since the type is existential?

Comment: @AJFarmar There are two standard tricks for encoding existentials in Haskell: via CPS (`exists e. List e a` -> `(EList a -> b, NEList a -> b) -> b`) and existential wrappers (`data SomeList a where SomeList :: List e a -> SomeList a`; sometimes paired with a GADT that lets you recover `e`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing you can do is pass around an alternative for empty lists:

```
lastDef :: a -> List e a -> a
lastDef a Nil = a
lastDef _ (Cons a b) = lastDef a b
```

Then wrap it up once at the top level.

```
last :: NEList a -> a
last (Cons a b) = lastDef a b
```

Extending this pattern to `foldr` and `foldr1` is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I happen to have pre-emptively completed that exercise! I suppose the reason for needing this pattern is that GHC checks for exhaustive patterns only *after* type-checking?

Comment: @AJFarmar I think part of what makes it tricky to know that "`Cons a Nil` doesn't match" implies "`Cons a (Cons b _)` does match" is that, in the presence of GADTs, it's not always clear that all constructors are type-correct possibilities, so it's not correct to simply try all the constructors not yet listed. For example, suppose that your lists had three constructors; which, if any, of the two remaining patterns' type equalities should be introduced on the right-hand side of `last (Cons a Nil) = a; last (Cons a b) = {- here -}`?

Comment: @AJFarmar And, by the way, if you already have `foldr` and `foldr1`, you could consider `last = foldr1 (\x y -> y)`.

Answer (score 3):

You've "defined" `NEList` (I say that in a loose way) the same way `base` defines `NonEmpty`: as a single element tacked onto the head of a potentially empty list.

```
data NonEmpty a = a :| [a]
```

Another presentation of `NonEmpty` instead places that single element at the end.

```
data NonEmpty a = Single a | Multiple a (NonEmpty a)
```

This presentation, no surprise, makes `eLast` easy:

```
eLast (Single x) = x
eLast (Multiple _ xs) = eLast xs
```

Whenever you want multiple sets of constructors on the same type, look to pattern synonyms. Instead of the base `NonEmpty`, we can also translate to your `List`.

```
pattern Single :: forall e a. () => e ~ 'NotEmpty => a -> List e a
pattern Single x = Cons x Nil
pattern Multiple :: forall e a. () => e ~ 'NotEmpty => a -> List 'NotEmpty a -> List e a
pattern Multiple x xs <- Cons x xs@(Cons _ _)
  where Multiple x xs = Cons x xs
-- my dormant bidirectional pattern synonyms GHC proposal would allow just
-- pattern Multiple x (Cons y xs) = Cons x (Cons y xs)
-- but current pattern synonyms are a little stupid, so Multiple is ugly
{-# COMPLETE Nil, Single, Multiple :: List #-}
-- Single and Multiple are actually patterns on List e a, not List NotEmpty a
-- Therefore the COMPLETE must include Nil, or else we'd show that all
-- Lists are nonempty (\case { Single _ -> Refl; Multiple _ _ -> Refl })
-- They are, however, still complete on List NotEmpty a
-- GHC will "infer" this by "trying" the Nil constructor and deeming it impossible
```

Giving

```
eLast :: NEList a -> a
eLast (Single x) = x
eLast (Multiple _ xs) = eLast xs
```